# vector vrl reduce: how to modify a field in a `reduce` transform to include the count of the reduced events/lines?

Tags: vector-vrl

I'm using `vector` to process `journald` logs posted to a `qryn` (`loki`-like) instance.
There are services that sometimes log many warnings in bursts for a certain function (remapped to the `.Function` field, so did this in the reduce transform:

```json
          type = "reduce",
          inputs = [ "t_my_remapped" ],
          expire_after_ms = 5000,
          flush_period_ms = 1000,
          group_by = [ "Function" ],
          merge_strategies.Function = "retain"
```

This is working, but I want to modify the `.Function` field to indicate how many events this was reduced from, something like `.Function = .Function + " (" + reduced_count + ")"`

But in the docs I can't seem to find a way to modify a field in a `reduce` type `transform`, and also no access to the "hook" or "callback" that happens during `flush` (where this type of functionality would normally go, I guess).